# Date format 24h without a space preceding single digits

Tags: php, time, strftime

I have the following

```
$nextDisponibility->formatLocalized('%A %e %B à %kh%M')
```

which gives me

> lundi 13 novembre à  8h00

How could I remove the space before the single hour digit ?

From [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php):

> **%k**    Hour in 24-hour format, with a space preceding single digits    0 through 23

Is `preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $nextDisponibility->formatLocalized('%A %e %B à %kh%M'));` the best way to do this ?

Comment: how about `str_replace('  ',' ',$string)`? (two spaces in the first argument)

Comment: You can `$day = $nextDisponibility->formatLocalized('%A %e %B'); $hour = $nextDisponibility->formatLocalized('%kh%M'); echo $day." à ".trim($hour);` that way you are sure not to remove other spaces that you may want to keep

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do string manipulations you can probably do something more "hacky":

```
$string = $nextDisponibility->formatLocalized('%A ')
.trim($nextDisponibility->formatLocalized("%e"))
.$nextDisponibility->formatLocalized(" %B ")
.ltrim($nextDisponibility->formatLocalized("%kh%M"));
```

However `$string = str_replace('  ',' ',$nextDisponibility->formatLocalized('%A %e %B à %kh%M'))` is probably better if you don't care about other double spaces.